# Programmatically creating forms - default selected index of a select

Tags: php, drupal

Part of a form I've created in Drupal 6 is:

```
  $form['limiter'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#id' => 'limiter',
        '#options' => array('10'=>'10','25'=>'25','50'=>'50')
      );
```

Which works fine.

However how do I define the default selected index so '25' is selected when the page loads? Anything I pass to '#default_value' doesn't seem to work.

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It's through `#default_value` - if that's not working, there's some other problem with your code external to the snippet you attached.  Note that `#default_value` will only work on the first load of the page; afterwards the value selected by the user will override it.

```
$form['limiter'] = array (
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#id' => 'limiter',
    '#options' => array('10'=>'10','25'=>'25','50'=>'50'),
    '#default_value' => '25'
);
```

See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#default_value

Comment: Yes, this is the answer and works.  Make sure you are including a comma at the end of the '#options' line